# JPA query equals between two properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

It is possible to compare two properties with JPA custom query ?

Registration.java :

```
@Entity
public class Registration implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
private UUID uuid;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Entry.class)
private Entry entry;

@ManyToMany(targetEntity=Rate.class,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Rate> rate;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Planning> planning;

}
```

Rate.java :

```
@Entity
public class Rate implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
private UUID uuid;

@ManyToOne
private Activity activity;
}
```

Planning.java :

```
@Entity
public class Planning implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
private UUID uuid;

@OneToOne
private Location location;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Coach coach;

@OneToOne
private Activity activity;
```

I would retrieve only rate.activity.id = planning.activity.id with something like :

```
public interface RegistrationDao extends CrudRepository<Registration, UUID> {

    findByPlanningAndRateActivityEqualsPlanningActivityOrderByEntryLastnameAsc(Planning planning);

 }
```

Thanks

Comment: JPQL allows comparison of many fields of JPA entities. The "model" you present in not a JPA entity model.

Comment: Of course, It was to simplify.

Comment: so what is your question? How to form a JPQL query with something specific in mind (because all JPA tutorials cover this), or do you really mean something about Spring Data JPA?

Comment: I want do something like rates.activity.id = planning.activity.id. How to do with JPA key words. Of course `findByPlanningAndRateActivityEqualsPlanningActivityOrderByEntryLastnameAsc` doesnt works

Comment: There is no field "rates" so no idea what that means. As for some stupidly long method name, I'd guess this is Spring-Data-JPA (because nobody would use such names of their own choice)... in which case perhaps you ought to tag the question as that

Comment: "rates.activity.id = planning.activity.id" is a representation what I mean. I need to specify in JPA query  what rate.activity.id must be equals to planning.activity.id...

Comment: That method name tho...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than having a long method name you can have a JPA Query it will be something like this. Hope this helps.

```
@Query("select * FROM Registration REG,Entry E, Rate R,Planning P WHERE REG.id = :id and R.activity=P.activity ORDER BY E.lastname")

public List<Registration> <MethodName>(@Param("id") String registrationid);
```

Comment: Finally, this is which I have did.         `SELECT p FROM Registration r JOIN r.planning p JOIN r.rate rt WHERE p.uuid = :planning AND p.activity=rt.activity group by r.entry.lastname, rt.type.id` . THANKS

Answer (score 0):

I have changed for this solution but I dont think that is the good approach (where rateActivity and planningActivity have to have the same id)

```
public interface RegistrationDao extends CrudRepository<Registration, UUID> {

  Iterable<Registration> findByPlanningAndRateActivityEqualsAndPlanningActivityEqualsOrderByEntryLastnameAsc(Planning planning,Activity rateActivity,Activity planningActivity);

}
```